# Run custom command from gesture on edge of screen with Linux

Tags: linux, desktop-customization

On Linux, I’m looking for a software solution to execute a custom command by making a gesture with the mouse on an edge of the screen. For example, a custom command is executed by right-clicking on the right edge of the screen (not the angle). For now, I tried xfce4-hotcorner-plugin and Brightside but none of these tools allows to associate a custom command to the edges of the screen. Compiz allows you to do this, but I use a machine not compatible with Compiz.